# Can I use a model for predicting if the variables aren't linear?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, linear

I made a Linear Regression model that predicts better than my Lasso Regression & Random Forest
The linear regression model does not follow the assumptions (linearity)
Can I still use it for predictions?

Comment: Sure you can make transformations such as (a very standard procedure) to account for non-linearity: 
$$ \log{(x)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y $$

Comment: @N-wiseindependent How do I find which variables I must transform?

Comment: @Antonio That would be for a separate question. // Regarding predictions, you know you are capable of making predictions, since you had to make predictions to say which model predicts the best, so what do you mean when you ask if you can use the linear model to make predictions?

Comment: @Dave I'm asking if I **have** to make sure my model meets assumptions in order to use it for predictions and I don't, what are the drawbacks?

Comment: Sure, you can use it to make predictions. Linearity is never precisely true, except in degenerate cases such as with a single, binary X. So if linearity  (or more generally, correct functional specification) was a strict requirement, no one could ever use the model. Rather, the question is *degree* of violation. When the fitted function and the true function differ greatly, you can still use the fitted function, but other functions may provide better predictions. When the two are reasonably close, then the (incorrect) model will be adequate.